# Where can I find the source code of Python/C api functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to locate the source code for the C api function `PyObject_Call`. I could not find it in the CPython github repo. Maybe I am not looking into the right folder. Where can I find it?

Also, are Python/C api functions a part of the interpreter binary or are they in some shared library?

Comment: Did you try the search bar? It's the fifth hit when I [search for `PyObject_Call`](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=PyObject_Call&type=)

Comment: Thanks. I had done a google search but not searched in github.